# High uid error issue with Docker and CircleCI 2.0

Tags: docker, circleci

I'm trying to build a continuous integration flow with Circle Ci. When I push my code to github, the flow starts, but it stops with the error:

```
    Build-agent version 0.0.4071-34fe4dc (2017-09-05T01:33:40+0000)
Starting container micheleminno/elasticsearch:latest
  image cache not found on this host, downloading micheleminno/elasticsearch:latest
latest: Pulling from micheleminno/elasticsearch
42a816b9ad19: Pull complete
5dabff016c33: Pull complete
e22082c539e8: Pull complete
57845aa0da23: Pull complete
3da62a3688f0: Pull complete
bce992ca3d80: Pull complete
2734c785c0d8: Pull complete
08cbf6dbba97: Pull complete
750b60032fcc: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f07025f1da82ea87e70cac194929953a245ae4560086471c90b1756693246ec4
Status: Downloaded newer image for micheleminno/elasticsearch:latest
  using image micheleminno/elasticsearch@sha256:f07025f1da82ea87e70cac194929953a245ae4560086471c90b1756693246ec4
Starting container mysql:5.5
  using image mysql@sha256:7674d74d9f010b1500c1ae38f7af90014145ee3c92ddd65dd2e1edfd8c61270f
Starting container micheleminno/db-migrations
  image cache not found on this host, downloading micheleminno/db-migrations
latest: Pulling from micheleminno/db-migrations
c89e59f636b6: Pull complete
cfb692fa93ee: Pull complete
d607b85c45a1: Pull complete
0150b9c56763: Pull complete

CircleCI was unable to start the container because of a userns remapping failure in Docker.

This typically means the image contains files with UID/GID values that are higher than Docr and CircleCI can use.

Checkout our docs https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/high-uid-error/ to learn how to fix this problem.

Original error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 5924152 cannot be mapped to a host ID
```

I followed the [link](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/high-uid-error/) and did what it suggests there, but I couldn't find anything with that ID.

Here's my config circle yml file:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: micheleminno/elasticsearch:latest
      - image: mysql:5.5
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: real-affinities-test
          MYSQL_USER: development
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: development
      - image: micheleminno/db-migrations
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV: development

    working_directory: ~/

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Build real-affinities and run tests
          command: docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml -p ci up --build
```

UPDATE 09/09/2017:

I followed @FelicianoTech suggestion to change ownership of files directly in Dockerfile, updating the Dockerfile of the project which causes the high uids issue:

```
FROM node:8.1.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# add package.json and run npm install before adding the rest of the files
# this way, you only run npm install when package.json changes
ADD package.json /app
RUN npm install

# add the rest of the files
ADD . /app

# change ownership recursively of all files
RUN chown root:root . -R

CMD ["./node_modules/.bin/knex", "migrate:latest"]
```

But the issue is still there.

Comment: Firstly, I think you should read through the Docker docs on CircleCI. A lot looks incorrect here. After rewriting somethings, maybe you can avoid this issue completely.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do like you suggest.

Comment: I looked up, studied and tried a little bit, I updated the config.yml file, but still getting the same error.

Comment: If the CircleCI config above up-to-date? I tried pulling the first image and that part works for me. For Docker Compose, you'd need setup_remote_docker.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the third Docker image, `micheleminno/db-migrations`. If you run the image locally, and run this command:

`ls -lah /app/node_modules/`

you'll see several directories have a user ID above 65534. That is the issue. Change those IDs to something lower to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I found those high IDs and changed them. But when I run the image again with: docker run -it micheleminno/db-migrations sh, they are back to original high uids. Perhaps something is missing in my docker knowledge..

Comment: The IDs need to be changed in the Dockerfile. Changing them via `docker exec` or similar just changes them in the running container. That container eventually gets remade which causes the same issue all over again unless you fix it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see the above update.